# Different random effects in nlme and nlmer

Tags: multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I estimated a nonlinear exponential $f(t)=\alpha-(\alpha-\beta)*\exp(-\gamma*t)$ random effects model in `R`. I estimated the same model form using the identical data set but with `nlme()` from the `nlme` library and `nlmer()` from the `lme4` library.

The fixed effect estimates are quite similar comparing `nlme` with `nlmer`:

**nlme:**

```
Fixed effects: alpha + beta + gamma ~ 1 
          Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
alpha 29.508227 0.4166492 3498 70.82272       0
beta   5.082116 0.1584696 3498 32.06998       0
gamma  0.313008 0.0070209 3498 44.58244       0
```

**nlmer:**

```
Fixed effects:
      Estimate Std. Error t value
alpha  30.0432     0.5432   55.31
beta    4.9541     0.2110   23.47
gamma   0.2551     0.0135   18.90
```

However, the random effects estimates along with their correlation matrix are different. This is a consistent finding. It also holds for other nonlinear functions and other data. See e.g. the correlation between alpha and gamma. It is also striking how large the variances in `nlmer` are -- they actually appear to be far too large

**nlme:**

```
> VarCorr(model)
Subject = pdLogChol(list(alpha ~ 1,beta ~ 1,gamma ~ 1)) 
         Variance    StdDev   Corr         
alpha    42.19955753 6.496119 alpha  beta  
beta      4.84969745 2.202203  0.494       
gamma     0.01055961 0.102760 -0.643  0.202
Residual  1.94836594 1.395839
```

**nlmer:**

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name  Variance  Std.Dev. Corr          
 Subject  alpha 72.551249 8.51770                
          beta   9.840010 3.13688   0.458        
          gamma  0.043274 0.20802  -0.195  0.142 
 Residual        1.716048 1.30998                
Number of obs: 3750, groups: Subject, 250
```

What is the problem here? Why are the variances in `nlmer` almost twice as large as those given in the `nlme` solution?

Comment: I think you should reconsider the statement that the fixed effects are similar.  Look at gamma.  They differ by many standard deviations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short:** It's lack of precision in nlmer

In order to obtain the same results as nlme I needed to move away form the laplacian approximatoin which is set with nAGQ=1. According to the nlmer manpage the nAGQ sets the number of points per axis for the evaluation of the adaptive Gauss-Hermite approximation. Basically, increasing the number of points per axis increases precision.

With nAGQ=2 random and fixed effects are virtually the same - this is also the case for the SD of the fixed effecs, as John had noted. In the present case increasing the nAGQ to 2 or 3 does the trick, however, larger numbers will slow down the computation and maybe reach the iteration limit without convergence.

I guess it's good practice to run the model with the standard settings and then go back and increase the precision to see if, and how strong the parameter estimates change.

For the present model it takes

- 10 sec with nAGQ=1
- 22 sec with nAGQ=2
- 24 with nAGQ=3

nAGQ=4 does not converge within the given iterations. 
In my case, the results obtained from nAGQ=2 and nAGQ=3 were the same.

As a comparison,

- in nlme it takes 3.8 seconds

to obtain the result, which I find quite surprising because in the past I had the impression that nlmer is faster than nlme.

**Bottom line:** It's probably safer to use nlme, as long as lme4 and with it nlmer is under development.